# Installing Intervention Image without composer

Tags: php, intervention

I would like to test [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io). It looks like a nice package. The installation instructions say:

> The best way to install Intervention Image is quickly and easily with
>   Composer.

The sentence above implies there's also a inferior, slower and difficult,  way to install it. I assume the author is referring to an installation without Composer? That is exactly what I am looking for!

However, I am unable to find a way to do that. I have looked for an autoloader file, or even any autoload call in the code. There's none. No documentation either. It seems that only an installation with Composer is supported in a meaningful way.

Has anybody of you tried to use Intervention Image without resorting to Composer?

Comment: do you have a valid reason not to use composer? what kinda of autoloader ( if any ) are you using in your project?

Comment: @Federkun No, I probably do not have a reason that you will find convincing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way without composer is simply to fetch the source from [github](https://github.com/Intervention/image), move it in one off your vendor directories and load all needed files.

As there's no autoload file provided inside the package, you have to extend your own autoload script or register a new autoload handler, as including each required file is a really annyoing task.

If you take a deeper look inside the composer.json file, you may notice inside the `require` section, that this package also need Guzzle. If you want to install [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle), you will again read the sentence "The recommended way to install Guzzle is through Composer". So you have to do the same thing again for Guzzle. This time you need the other two Guzzle dependencies `psr7` and `promises`....

At this point, I hope you build your autoloader robust enough to simply add only a new mapping from namespace prefix to path, as their might be many other required packages.

---

If you don't want to include composer directly inside your project, for what reasons ever, you could also create a empty composer project, just for managing the dependencies and the autoloader. That might be easier to do everything by hand.

Note: If you are lucky, you could use the Intervention/Image package
without the guzzle dependency.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I was afraid of. I know how to do this, and I know it's quite a bit of work. Not something I am prepared to do for a simple test of the software. I will probably have to find a way to install and use Composer. It's supposed to make live easier, but only for those who use it and accept the consequences.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thats why I sad, you could also create an empty composer project just for managing the dependencies and the autoloader. In this case, you only have to include the autoloader file from the php project and keep everything else, as it is

Comment: Oh, and in case of this package, I'm pretty sure, you could run it without guzzle, so it might be even easy possible to run it without composer